# How to run program once it is saved in $PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, android, environment-variables, android-studio

I just saved a new program "android studio" to my path environment variables like the install page suggests. "[Tip: Add android-studio/bin/ to your PATH environment variable so you can start Android Studio from any directory.](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)"

Now that it is saved there I don't know what the command is to run it globally. I tried "android-studios" and "android".

**Question:**

Now that the program is saved to path what else do I need to do to run to the executable globally?

Comment: what is the exact name of the binary file ? call that in command line

Answer (score 2):

Before you put the directory inside `$PATH`, you execute Android Studio like

```
$ /path/to/your/installation/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Now that you put `/path/to/your/installation/android-studio/bin` in your path, that means for every executable in that folder, you can just call its name. Therefore, now you need

```
$ studio.sh
```

And your Android Studio should start.

Notice that if you just changed your `$PATH` in your current shell, then your change won't be saved across shell sessions. Remember to put the change of your `$PATH` to your rc file like

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/installation/android-studio/bin:$PATH
```

If you use `zsh`, that would be `~/.zshrc`. If you use some other shell, go search online what the name of the rc file is.

Comment: So if I'm using a bash shell does that mean that the rc file I need to update is the ``.bashrc`` file?

Comment: @NickPineda Yup that's right. The file is located in your home directory, so just open it by accessing `~/.bashrc` and add the line to the end of the file. Then you either do `source ~/.bashrc` or you open a new terminal. And then you can open Android Studio using `studio.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The guide says:

> 2. To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the `android-studio/bin/` directory, and **execute `studio.sh`**.
>
>    Tip: Add `android-studio/bin/` to your `PATH` environment variable so you can start Android Studio from any directory.

So the name of the executable you need to run is `studio.sh`.

Comment: does that mean I can execute ``studio.sh`` from anywhere in the command line?

Comment: Yes. Just try it.